# WMI C++ get data from object

Tags: c++, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

I implemented 1-5 steps from :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx
Everyting works, but i have problem with getting data from object which i retreive with query.

My code:

```
// Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
// Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    //cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
    //    << hex << hres << endl;
    return 1;                  // Program has failed.
}

// Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
// Set general COM security levels --------------------------

hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL, 
    -1,                          // COM authentication
    NULL,                        // Authentication services
    NULL,                        // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
    NULL,                        // Authentication info
    EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
    NULL                         // Reserved
    );


if (FAILED(hres))
{
    //cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
    //    << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                    // Program has failed.
}

// Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
// Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------
pLoc = NULL;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,             
    0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    //cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
    //    << " Err code = 0x"
    //    << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                 // Program has failed.
}

// Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
// Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
pSvc = NULL;

// Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
// the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
// to make IWbemServices calls.
hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
     _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
     NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
     NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
     0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
     NULL,                    // Security flags.
     0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
     0,                       // Context object 
     &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
     );

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    //cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
    //     << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}

//OutputDebugString("Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace");
// Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
// Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
   pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
   RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
   RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
   NULL,                        // Server principal name 
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
   NULL,                        // client identity
   EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}
```

code above is the same as msdn example.

Problem is here:

```
// Get the currently inserted USB devices
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    //cout << "Query for USB devices at startup failed."
    //    << " Error code = 0x" 
    //    << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}

// Get the data from the query 
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;   
ostringstream os;
while (pEnumerator){
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);
    if(0 == uReturn){
        break;
    }
    VARIANT vtProp;
    VariantInit(&vtProp);
    // Get the value of the accessstate property
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Dependent", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr)){        
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }
    os.str("");
    os.clear();
    os << vtProp.bstrVal;
    OutputDebugString(os.str().c_str());
    AddDevice(os.str());//Add device to devices vector
    VariantClear(&vtProp);  
    pclsObj->Release();
}
```

Exactly in this place:

```
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Dependent", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

This link describes table elements:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394505(v=vs.85).aspx
So i got Dependent value. My problem is how to get this Dependent properties:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387884(v=vs.85).aspx
for example : DeviceID
If anyone can help i will be very very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried calling ``VariantInit`` on ``vtProp`` before calling ``Get``?

Comment: Also, you don't check for the ``HRESULT`` from ``Get`` for failure. What is it? Be sure to check *all* ``HRESULT`` values for failure.

Comment: I did do this, still the same issue, i am getting reference to database record in vtProp, dont know ho to take values.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, I USED WRON CODING INSTEAD USE UTF-16 AND I SHOW MY ERROR USING OutputDebugStringW(vtProp.bstrVal); !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks for showing good programming techniques!                  OutputDebugStringW(vtProp.bstrVal) works!!!